# if statement doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, if-statement

In Wordpress, I'm trying to add the post ID of posts I publish in a new table if not already there (to avoid double entries when updating posts from the admin panel)

```
if( $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM wp_post_votes WHERE post_id != $post_ID" ) ) {
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'post_votes', array( 'post_id' => $post_ID ) );
    }
```

This statement works only with a = operator and an "else ( do code.. }". With != nothing happens I can't figure out why.. I just want to keep the code as short as possible.

Comment: Have you tried to look what `$wpdb->get_row(...)` returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM wp_post_votes WHERE post_id = $post_ID" ) ) ) {
    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'post_votes', array( 'post_id' => $post_ID ) );
}
```

Should be what you're looking for.  (Added a ! before the conditional to simulate your "else" effect)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense thanks! Do you recommend I also add end(); or exit(); ? the statement is in a function with return $somevariable after the closing if bracket.

Comment: I don't know the rest of the flow of your app, so I'm not sure.  Try it and see if it breaks.  You might not need the extra few cycles of cpu time if there's a chance that just exit()ing will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if( !$wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM wp_post_votes WHERE post_id = $post_ID" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is checking that the output from

```
$wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM wp_post_votes WHERE post_id != $post_ID" )
```

evaluates to a true-like value.  You're essentially running a query that selects all IDs from ALL rows (except for perhaps one).  This is inefficient and probably not what you wanted - you probably wanted to check if a matching row was not found, not that non-matching rows were found.

You probably want:

```
if (!$wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM wp_post_votes WHERE post_id = $post_ID" )) {
```